# Dynamically increment SafeHtmlTemplates variable value during runtime

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to increment (or change in general) added value to interface during run time? For example, integer is used as a variable, would it be possible to increment the variable after it was added?

Let's say I have SafeHtmlTemplates interface:

```
public interface MyTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<div id=\"{0}\"></div>") 
    SafeHtml temp(Integer id);
}
```

If I were to use it:

```
MyTemplate tpls = GWT.create(MyTemplate.class);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    tpls.temp(i);
}
```

I would get:

```
<div id="0"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
```

However I would like to get:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

By incrementing {0} after it's added somehow (something like `{0} + {offsetVariable}`, so far I think that's not possible (or am just unable to figure out how to do that).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper class like this:

```
public class MyTemplateHelper implements MyTemplate {

    private MyTemplate tpls = GWT.create(MyTemplate.class);

    @Override
    public SafeHtml temp(Integer id) {
        return tpls.temp(id + 1);
    }
}
```

Please, notice that `MyTemplateHelper` can implement `MyTemplate`.

Compare usage:

```
MyTemplate tpls;

tpls = GWT.create(MyTemplate.class);    // original template class
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    tpls.temp(i);

//  you'll get:
//  <div id="0"></div>
//  <div id="1"></div>

tpls = new MyTemplateHelper();          // helper class
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    tpls.temp(i);

//  you'll get:
//  <div id="1"></div>
//  <div id="2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I've been looking for (seems so obvious now that you've shown it to me)